# Error creating QField project

Tags: error, qfield

I work currently with QField Cloud.
Today I tried to create a new project but it doesn’t work.

[image]

When I try to create a new QField Project from current project it show me always this error:

```
[{"id":"c0f8877b-8197-4abe-8ee7-b536f18d0665",
  "name":"Yaali",
  "owner":"abdi",
  "description":"polygon mapping on the field",
  "private":false,
  "is_public":true,
  "created_at":"2022-06-05T18:57:51.409650+02:00",
  "updated_at":"2022-06-05T18:57:51.409687+02:00",
  "data_last_packaged_at":null,
  "data_last_updated_at":null,
  "can_repackage":true,
  "needs_repackaging":true,
  "status":"failed",
  "user_role":"reader",
  "user_role_origin":"public"
 },{
  "id":"1ba2cce1-6a96-4119-863e-3818263f2d6e",
  "name":"percobaan",
  "owner":"abdill…
```

What happened? How can I solve the problem?

I already reinstalled the QGIS and QField but the problem persists.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.